# Monogame Content Pipeline unable to load type

Tags: xml, monogame

I've been trying to get Xml serialization working on a project of mine, writing the XML to an object. I believe I have the code and such right, but the pipeline tool refuses to build the Xml file becuase it is "Unable to load one or more of the requested types."

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that my code and objects are all in-program, and not in a separate DLL. Every solution I've seen to this is to reference the DLL in the mgcb, but that isn't possible in this case.

How do I get it to reference a class, if that's even possible? Otherwise, how do I get it to perhaps bypass typing on build?

Comment: If you parse XML files via C# code you do not need to pass the file through the pipeline. .Net can open/edit/etc. files on his own

Answer (score 0):

Select the Xml document in the MonoGame Pipeline Tool.
In the Properties panel, click Build Action, and from the dropdown, change it from Build to Copy.